# AngularJs - Best way to include my service inside every controller?

Tags: angularjs

I'm building a small two-language app with the use of [angular-translate](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate). I want to have a language switcher in every view (controller). I'm trying to figure out how to put the code responsible for language switching into every controller. The code looks like this:

```
var langSwitch =  $Scope.setLang = function (langKey) {
    $translate.use(langKey);
};
```

So far I've figured that I can create a factory that looks like this:

```
app.factory('langSwitch', function ($rootScope, $translate) {
    var langSwitch =  $rootScope.setLang = function (langKey) {
        $translate.use(langKey);
    };
    return langSwitch;
});
```

and inject it into controllers in this maner:

```
app.controller('HomeCtrl', function (langSwitch) {
  // normal controller code here 
});
```

This works but 1) I'm using $rootScope and I have a feeling this is bad practice & 2) jsHint screams that "langSwitch" is not defined. Maybe there is a simpler way to make the function global without putting it into every controller?
I'm still pretty new to Angular so don't scream at me :) Thanks.

**edit**

My view:

```
<button ng-click="setLang('en_GB')">English</button>
<button ng-click="setLang('pl_PL')">Polish</button>
```

Comment: I use $rootScope its convenient but risky because of name collision. You can however add a property "appGlobal" and store your stuff in it such as $rootScope.appGlobal.something to reduce the risk of overriding an existing property.

Comment: It seems unlikely that the service will be required in every single controller for the future of the application. I would just reference the service as you've shown. It kind of defeats the whole point of angular's dependency injection to put things in global space. I don't think there is anything wrong with having a reference to the service in every controller. It would be easier understood by other angular devs too, rather than having a mystery global that would need to be documented.

Answer (score 1):

Although you got the idea, you overcomplicated things a bit. You could declare the service as follows:

```
app.service('langSwitch', function ($translate) {
    this.setLang = function (langKey) {
        $translate.use(langKey);
    };
});
```

And then inject `langSwitch` in the controller responsible for lang switching, as you already did. No need to inject `$rootScope` in the service.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work, I forgot to add how the view works. I've edited the OP. I think I need some sort of scope for `<button ng-click="setLang('en_GB')">English</button>` so that I can pass in the parameters.

Comment: Ok, now I understand why you referenced the `setLang` function in the `$rootScope`. Can you precise one thing: do you have the language switcher in a header or something like that, or is the button duplicated in different views?

Comment: It's duplicated in each view, that's the reason why I want to include it in every controller.

Comment: The fact that the button is duplicated is actually where the problem resides. You should make a directive, that is a typical use case for that. Then in the controller of the directive, expose a `setLang` function that will call the service responsible for language switching.

Comment: Ok, I will try to do this today, I'll report back later on. Thanks!

Comment: I removed the service and created a directive that looks like this:
https://jsbin.com/digowoxuxa/edit?html,js,output
This works but is it a good solution?  [In case the link gets deleted: the directive creates has a template with 2 btns and a link to the function of setLang; the view looks like this: `<div lang-select></div>`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need $rootScope indeed unless you need to process some global events in your application. All services and factories in angular are singletons by default. That means once it created, it will be passed as the same instance in every place it is declared as a dependency. So if you want to share data and functionality between different controllers - the services will suit fine. You can change your factory code to:

```js
app.factory('langSwitch', function($translate) {
  return {
    setLang: function(langKey) {
      $trasnlate.use(langKey);
    };
  };
});
```